# Do not want to remove "_" using isalnum() in Python

Tags: python

I need to create an exception for `isalnum()` to not remove the "_" after the word NOT

This is the data structure I have

```
 data = ['TEXT TEXT. TEXT! NOT_TEXT', 'TEXT? NOT_TEXT, TEXT NOT_TEXT']
```

The code I have:

```
for text in range(len(data)):
    data_new = ["".join([char for char in text if char.isalnum() or char == " "]) for text in data]
```

Outcome I have:

```
['TEXT TEXT TEXT NOTTEXT', 'TEXT NOTTEXT TEXT NOTTEXT']
```

However, I need to create an exception for `isalnum()` to not remove the "_" after the word NOT

expected outcome:

```
['TEXT TEXT TEXT NOT_TEXT', 'TEXT NOT_TEXT TEXT NOT_TEXT']
```

Answer (score 2):

`isalnum` is part of the decision of which characters to keep. So is `== ' '`. You can add one more item to the condition:

```
char.isalnum() or char in " _"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already has an exception for space characters, so why don’t you simply augment that to also include the underscore character? Also, your outer `for` loop is redundant, and your formatting could be improved, i.e. it’s better to not write the whole code on one line.

The following snippet is still not perfect, but it does what you want. I’m sure you can improve on it further.

```
data = ['TEXT TEXT. TEXT! NOT_TEXT', 'TEXT? NOT_TEXT, TEXT NOT_TEXT']

data_new = [
    "".join(
        char for char in text if char.isalnum() or char in (" _")
    ) for text in data
]

print (data_new)
```

Comment: you can convert inner list comprehension to generator -> data_new = [
    "".join(char for char in text if char.isalnum() or char in (" _"))
    for text in data
]

Comment: @Nk03 Right, that gets rid of one level of brackets. Thanks for the suggestion. I’ve done the edit while keeping the formatting.

Comment: It's not just getting rid of extra brackets - generator in python are different from list comprehensions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the desired output, you can use regex.

```py
import re

data = ["TEXT TEXT. TEXT! NOT_TEXT", "TEXT? NOT_TEXT, TEXT NOT_TEXT"]

for item in data:
    data_new = re.findall(r"\w+", item)
    print(data_new)
```

**Output**

```
['TEXT', 'TEXT', 'TEXT', 'NOT_TEXT']
['TEXT', 'NOT_TEXT', 'TEXT', 'NOT_TEXT']
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```py
new_data = [re.findall(r"\w+", item) for item in data]
```